# Hierarchy classes dependency

Tags: c++, class-design

I want some advice about class designs.
Let's say that I have 3 classes, `"class A", "class B" and "class C"`.
Each class has different namespaces.
`"A" has an instance of "B", and "B" has an instance of "C"`.
Each class have a "struct Setting" and each class is set with a SetSettings().
Actually, `"A" uses "B" to do its job, and "B" uses "C" to do its job`.

My question is, is there any better way to do these hierarchy settings?

For example, `to break the relation between "A" and "C", "B"` could have the same parameters of `"C::Settings"` instead of defining a c_settings...

Thanks in advance!

**A.h**

```
#include "B.h"
namespace A {
struct Settings {
  int param_for_A_1;
  B::Settings b_settings;
};
class A {
  void SetSettings(const Settings& source) {
    settings_ = source;
    b_.SetSettings(source.b_settings);
  }
  Settings settings_;
  B::B b_;
};
}
```

**B.h**

```
#include "C.h"
namespace B {
struct Settings {
  int param_for_B_1;
  int param_for_A_2;
  C::Settings c_settings;
};
class B {
  void SetSettings(const Settings& source) {
    settings_ = source;
    c_.SetSettings(source.c_settings);
  }
  Settings settings_;
  C::C c_;
};
}
```

**C.h**

```
namespace C {
struct Settings {
  int param_for_C_1;
};
class C {
  void SetSettings(const Settings& source) {
    settings_ = source;
  }
  Settings settings_;
};
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"
int main() {
  A::Settings settings;
  // Hierarchy settings...
  settings.param_for_A_1 = 1;
  settings.b_settings.param_for_B_1= 2;
  settings.b_settings.param_for_B_2 = 3;
  settings.b_settings.c_settings.param_for_C_1= 4;
  class A::A a;
  a_.SetSettings(settings);
  return;
}
```

Comment: 1) depends on how visible you want to have c-class in your application. 2) I somehow dont get your reason for using that strcut to bundle an int to those classes :(

Comment: Thanks for your comment Najzero.  1)In this example hierarchy is not so deep by in my actual project the hierarchy is deeper and I wanted to hide lower levels.  2)Actually there are few parameters depending on the class.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, you are not indeed using inheritance, but rather composition. Composition means that a class has an attribute of the type of another class, rather than inheriting the functions and attributes of a parent class.

If I wanted to use inheritance, I probably would have used the class C as a base from which B would inherit. A would then inherit from B. Each "generation" having their own `int` attribute corresponding to their "settings".

Depending on the situation, this might be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Matzar. I'm really sorry for the lack of info, but "A", "B" and "C" are "has-a" case and not "is-a" case, so composition was better for me.

Comment: Well, I don't have much more to say then. :P Without a context it is hard to improve the code. For example, I don't immediately see the use in having `C::Settings c_settings` in the struct for `B` AND having an instance of the class `C` as an attribute, whose only attribute is `c_settings`.

I'm also fairly new to programming (< 1 year), so sorry for not being much help. Hope you find your answer.

Comment: The relation between these classes: "A" uses "B" to do its job, and "B" uses "C" to do its job. Thanks anyway!